# Listview set adapter fragment nullpointerexception

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, fragment, adapter

I currently have 3 fragments but I am not able to get my adapter working.
When I am calling lv.setAdapter(lbadapter) it returns a nullpointer exception.
What could be the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Here's a part of my fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leadlist, container, false);



    profielen = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    new getLeaderboards().execute(url);

    lv = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lbadapter = new LeaderBoardAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.item_layout, profielen);


    return rootView;
}

public static class getLeaderboards extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JsonObject> {


    @Override
    protected JsonObject doInBackground(String... urls) {

        JsonObject x = parseURL.GetJSON(urls[0]);

        return x;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JsonObject obj) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray arr = obj.get("rows").getAsJsonArray();

        for (JsonElement el : arr) {
            Profile pat = gson.fromJson( el , Profile.class);
            profielen.add(pat);
        }

        lv.setAdapter(lbadapter);


    }

}
```

Here's my leadlist.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp" >
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My adapter :

```
    public class LeaderBoardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile>{

LayoutInflater vi;
List<Profile> profielen;
Context mContext;
int res;
public LeaderBoardAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Profile> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.res = resource;
    this.profielen = objects;
    mContext = context;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ProfileHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);

        holder = new ProfileHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameChar);
        holder.pic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageChar);
        holder.rank = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingNumber);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ProfileHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Profile p = profielen.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(p.getName());
    holder.rank.setText(p.getRanking());

    return convertView;

}

public static class ProfileHolder{
    TextView name;
    ImageView pic;
    TextView rank;
}





}
```

Comment: try to start AsyncTask after initializing ListView

Comment: can any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148618/listview-not-refreshing-after-click-on-button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lv = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Instead  do this. Since the list view is not directly related to your `Activity`. It is the enclosing view inside the fragment which is holding the `ListView`

```
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. By the way a little other question, Do you need a seperate layout for each fragment or is one layout enough?

Comment: Which is based on what you need to show inside the fragment.

Comment: One will work fine if you need same UI on each fragment.

Comment: Yeah in that case you can use the same fragment itself

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to do like that

```
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

instead of

```
lv = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Assuming the list view is in the fragment.

Comment: If you take a look at the time diff you can narrow down this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you have initialized your ListView. If you notice it belongs to your leadlist.xml file. However while initializing you are calling,

```
lv = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list); // this means your listView lv belongs to your MainActivity which actually doesn't.
```

Change this to,

```
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

and it should work. Lemme me how it goes. Happy coding :)